# How can i FADE IN and OUT a list that appears (using the .bind command?

Tags: jquery

This is the code i'm using. It's to make a list appear on `mousenter` the list's title. 
The thing is that it appears and disappears very abruptly. What can i do to make this smoother?

Many thanks for your time!

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var timeout    = 0;
var closetimer = 0;
var ddmenuitem = 0;

function jsddm_open()
{  jsddm_canceltimer();
   jsddm_close();
   ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');}

function jsddm_close()
{  if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');}

function jsddm_timer()
{  closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);}

function jsddm_canceltimer()
{  if(closetimer)
   {  window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
      closetimer = null;}}

$(document).ready(function()
{  $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseenter', jsddm_open) 
  $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseleave',  jsddm_timer)});

document.onclick = jsddm_close; </script>
```

Comment: I see you are using jQuery. Please, fix the formatting.

Comment: this looks like Javascript and JQuery - if so, you should tag the question as such to help people understand what they are looking at. it would also help if you formatted the code properly, see the '101010' button above the text editing area

Answer (score 1):

Your two lines that set visibility:

```
   ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');
   ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Try this instead:

```
   ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').show('slow');
   ddmenuitem.hide('slow');
```

Aside:

You last few lines could be this. Just a bit neater:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#jsddm > li').mouseover(jsddm_open) 
    $('#jsddm > li').mouseout(jsddm_timer)
    $(document).click(jsddm_close);
});
```

Or even:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#jsddm > li').hover(jsddm_open, jsddm_timer) 
    $(document).click(jsddm_close);
});
```